# How can I check by a button click which ip to connect?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-studio

On the **MainActivity.java** I have a method that connect with a server:

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr = urlIn;

        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);
            byte[] bufOut;

            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }

            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

I'm calling this method from `onTouchEvent()`:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    circlePath.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            byte[] response = null;
                            if (is_start == true)
                            {
                                response = Get("http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=start");
                                is_start = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               response = Get("http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=stop");
                                is_start = true;
                            }

                            if (response!=null)
                            {
                                String a = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    a = new String(response,"UTF-8");
                                    textforthespeacch = a;
                                    MainActivity.currentActivity.initTTS();
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    circlePath.reset();

                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

So now i'm connecting all the time to 10.0.0.2:8098
But that's when i connect my android device on my network on my pc room.

But if i move to the living room and connect to the network there a differenet network with another pc the pc ip is differenet in this case: 10.0.0.3:8099

So i added a button click event to the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

        currentActivity = this;

        initTTS();


    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

            }

        });

    }
```

Inside the button click event I want to check after connected to the network with a wifi if the pc ip is **10.0.0.3:8099 or 10.0.0.2:8098**

I need that it will try to connect to this servers and if success then to set to a global variable global string the ip.

I added a global variable: string ipaddress
Now i use static address in my code but i need to check which ip address is correct and then to set this ip to the variable which i will use later in my code as the ip address.

How do I make the checking in the button click event ?

This is what i tried now:

At the top of my MainActivity i added:

```
private final String[] ipaddresses = new String[2];
private final Integer[] ipports = new Integer[2];
Socket socket = null;
```

Then in the onCreate:

```
ipaddresses[0] = "10.0.0.3";
ipaddresses[1] = "10.0.0.2";
ipports[0] = 8098;
ipports[1] = 8088;
addListenerOnButton();
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
```

Then

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                    try {

                        String str = btnClick.getText().toString();
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


            }


        });

    }
```

And the ClientThread

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<ipaddresses.length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddresses[i]);

                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ipports[i]);

                } catch (UnknownHostException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This is a screenshot of the exception message i'm getting:

[image: Exception]

The exception is on the line:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
```

Comment: You can ping IP address to check whether the host is live or not!

Comment: You can better display an alert dialog where the user can choose between the two ip:port's.

Comment: I added to my question what i tried now. What i want to do is when i click the button it will loop over the ip addresses and the ports and check each ip and it's port. And to make that if there is a connection change the button text and for example show the button text as: Connected to 10.0.0.3:8098 and if the other ip and port connected show them as button text. But the way i did it now it's throwing exception on the PrintWriter.

Comment: Is exception thrown with two IP? Because it would be normal with non reachable IP

Comment: I added now to my question a screenshot with the exception message. I think it's something with the button btnClick ? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You must open sockets to check server connectivity. Here is an example on you send strings to server on click event:

```
public class Client extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 8099;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.3";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

So if you get an exception trying to connect to server, it means you haven't connectivity.

Comment: Updated my question with what i tried now. Not working.